# Tags input field in instance view at admin panel

Tags: django, django-taggit

I'm using django-taggit and its working fine, but one moment. When i open instance in django admin - tags input field autofill with following format:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5hL4.png)

is it possible to get tags input autofill format like this?
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7lDE.png)

Or disable autofill by default?
Django version 1.9, django-taggit 1.3.0

admin.py
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omZM1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use Magic method `def __str__(self)` function to stringify the queried data in table or anywhere in admin panel.

refer [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/change-object-display-name-using-__str__-function-django-models-python/) you will understand: